# JEditorPane.setpage no more work properly with java 1.6.22

Tags: java, applet

Now with new java 1.6.22 update installed (previous version was OK) my customers are reporting  a nasty issue.

editorPane.setPage()  throws exception *ONLY* when using my applet 2nd time
(meaning RELOADING my APPLET with browser or applet viewer)
Problem does not occur if RESTARTING applet, just when RELOADING.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser.errorContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.html.parser.DocumentParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane$PageLoader.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using m_editorPane.setEditorKitForContentType

How can I fix  my Applet so that setPage does not crash with new JRE 1.6.22
I cannot tell customers to use older JRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, [looks like a bug introduced in 1.6.0_22](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6993691).

There's a workaround described in that link.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, that bug is marked as a duplicate of an invalid bug.

Potentially related bug id:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6993073